# Формирование вложенного списка и вычисление суммы полей

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dict

В базе данных записи хранятся в таком виде:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пишу функцию, которая будет рассчитывать сумму заданных значений для разных переменных clu (например, q и е).
То есть сначала определяется, какие значения name соответствуют значению e (это three и four). Далее идет обращение к словарю "e", в котором хранятся определенные значения, соответсвующие разным name.
Функция должна определить, что для группы e необходимо сложить значения ключей "name" three и four и выдать результат.

Пример словаря e:

```
{'one': {'u_mean': 4.25, 'c_mean': 4.25}, 'three': {'u_mean': 4.5, 'c_mean': 4.5}, 'two': {'u_mean': 4.583333333333334, 'c_mean': 4.583333333333334}, 'four': {'u_mean': 4.5625, 'c_mean': 4.5625}, 'five': {'u_mean': 4.65, 'c_mean': 4.65}}
```

Результат должен быть такой:

```
 {'e': {'u_mean': 4.531, 'c_mean': 4.531}, 'q': {'u_mean': 4.49443, 'c_mean': 4.49443}}
```

То есть складываются поля все u_mean и находится их среднее, и также складываются.

Полный код моей функции:

```
def group_names():
    st, c_clus, n_names = [], [], []
    for h in Utilizations.objects.values('clu', 'name', 'a', 'b'):
        st.append((h.get('clu'), h.get('name'), h.get('a'), h.get('b')))
        c_clus.append(h.get('clu'))
        n_names.append(h.get('name'))
    """получение названий"""
    names, clus = [], []
    for nam in n_names:
        if nam not in names:
            names.append(nam)
    for cl in c_clus:
        if cl not in clus:
            clus.append(cl)
    clu, e = {}, {}
    u_load, u_max = {}, {}
    mean_all, u_load_mean, u_max_mean = 0, 0, 0
    for nam in names:
        hs = Utilizations.objects.filter(name=nam)
        o, p = 0, 0
        for h in hs:
            o += h.a
            p += h.b
            u_load[nam] = o / 2 + 1
            u_max[nam] = p / 2 + 1
        u_max_mean = mean(u_max.values())
        u_load_mean = mean(u_load.values())
        mean_all = (u_max_mean + u_load_mean) / 2
        e[nam] = {'u_mean': mean_all, 'c_mean': mean_all}
    for cl in clus:
        for nam in names:
            s = Utilizations.objects.filter(name=nam, clu=cl)
            for h in hs:
                clu[nam] = cl
    return clu
```

Получается сгруппировать в таком виде:
{'one': 'q', 'two': 'q', 'five': 'q', 'three': 'e', 'four': 'e'}

А как дальше не знаю(

Comment: Для начала отформатируйте нормально свой код, начиная со строки 1 (вернее - 2)

Comment: @passant готово

Comment: А теперь пытаемся перевести и разобраться что у вас написано. 1. "идет обращение к словарю "e", в котором хранятся определенные значения, соответсвующие разным name." Откуда в этом словаре берутся эти значения?  2. "сложить значения ключей "name" three и four" -  по какой формуле вы складываете два словаря, которые есть значениями указанных ключей? И что значит фраза "и находится их среднее, и также складываются." с чем складывается?  3. Причем к этому "складыванию" значения "суммы заданных значений для разных переменных clu". Что такое "разные ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ clu" я даже боюсь спрашивать.

Comment: Да, и из какого пакета вы вытянули объект utilizations.objects ?

Comment: @passat по порядку. В бд хранятся name и clu. Одному значению clu могут соответствовать несколько значений name, также в базе может находиться несколько записей name с одинаковыми названиями, но разными числовыми значениями в столбцах а и b. Для каждого отдельного name рассчитывается формула: (сумма значений отдельного столбца а и столбца b) /2 +1. В случае примера, поля name не дублируются, поэтому просто берется текущее поле a и b, которые соответствуют полю name. Полученные вычисления сохраняются в словарь e.
По таблице сверху видно, что для clu e соответсвуют 2 поля name:three и four.->

Comment: @passat значит, в словаре e нужно обратиться ключам three и four, найти их среднее арифметическое отдельно для u_mean(это будет 4.531), отдельно для c_mean(4.531). Сейчас значения равны, позже они будут различными. "3. Причем к этому "складыванию" значения "суммы заданных значений для разных переменных clu" - это нужно для того, чтобы понимать, какие ключи из словаря e вытаскивать. Опять же, для clu с именем e - это three и four, для clue "q" - остальные.
utilizations.objects - модель джанго, которая используется в работе, просто для работы с бд.

Comment: Так вам надо словари e,q.... и словарь-результат или достаточно одного результирующего словаря. И еще, как именно вы получили приведенные значения вашего словаря "e" на данных вашего примера (интересуют значения при 'one' , 'two', ''five'?

Answer (score 0):

Ну, поскольку вразумительного ответа на вопрос, а что-же действительно нужно ТС не последовало,  пришлось писать универсальное решение.

По сути оно состоит из двух частей. Часть первая -  собираем два универсальных DataFrame, отдельно для признака "a" и отдельно для признака "b".
(Тестовые данные немного расширены, что-бы захватить больше различных возможных случаев)

```
import pandas as pd
db=pd.DataFrame({'a':[8,10,7,20,7,6,6,1,2,3,4,5,7],
                 'b':[7,4,6,8,6,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,7],
                 'clu':['e','e','e','e','q','q','q','t','t','t','t','t','t'],
                 'name':['three','four','three','four','one','two','five',
                         'one','two','three','four','five','seven']})
clu_list=db.clu.unique()
name_list=db.name.unique()
db_a=pd.DataFrame(index=name_list)
db_b=pd.DataFrame(index=name_list)
for clu_ex in clu_list:
    db_a[clu_ex] = db.loc[db.clu==clu_ex].groupby(['name'])['a'].mean()
    db_b[clu_ex] = db.loc[db.clu==clu_ex].groupby(['name'])['b'].mean()
```

Имея эти DataFrame легко решаем разные варианты задачи.

Во-первых, вариант в котором для каждого 'clu' строиться свой словарь, которые в свою очередь объединяются словарь словарей.

```
d_l={}
for clu_ex in  clu_list: 
    d_r={}
    for row in name_list:
        a_p=db_a.loc[row][clu_ex]
        b_p=db_b.loc[row][clu_ex]
        d_r1={}
        if pd.notna(a_p):
            d_r1['u_mean']=a_p
        if pd.notna(b_p):
            d_r1['c_mean']=b_p
        if pd.notna(a_p) and pd.notna(b_p):
            d_r[row]=d_r1
    d_l[clu_ex]=d_r
print (d_l)
```

В результате получаем вот это:

```
{'e': {'three': {'u_mean': 7.5, 'c_mean': 6.5}, 'four': {'u_mean': 15.0, 
   'c_mean': 6.0}}, 
 'q': {'one': {'u_mean': 7.0, 'c_mean': 6.0}, 'two': {'u_mean': 6.0, 'c_mean': 
    9.0}, 'five': {'u_mean': 6.0, 'c_mean': 10.0}}, 
 't': {'three': {'u_mean': 3.0, 'c_mean': 3.0}, 'four': {'u_mean': 4.0, 
   'c_mean': 4.0}, 'one': {'u_mean': 1.0, 'c_mean': 1.0}, 'two': {'u_mean': 2.0, 
   'c_mean': 2.0}, 'five': {'u_mean': 5.0, 'c_mean': 5.0}, 'seven': {'u_mean': 
    7.0, 'c_mean': 7.0}}
 }
```

Во-вторых, если нужно построить общий словарь по каждому из значений переменной clu, то из тех-же промежуточных DataFrame они получаются следующим образом.

```
d_l={}
for clu_ex in  clu_list: 
    d_r1={}
    d_r1['u_mean']=db_a.mean()[clu_ex]
    d_r1['c_mean']=db_b.mean()[clu_ex]
    d_l[clu_ex]=d_r1
print (d_l)
```

В итоге получаем:

```
{'e': {'u_mean': 11.25, 'c_mean': 6.25}, 
 'q': {'u_mean': 6.333333333333333, 'c_mean': 8.333333333333334}, 
 't': {'u_mean': 3.6666666666666665, 'c_mean': 3.6666666666666665}}
```

В-третьих, если надо данные выдать по параметру name (что вроде бы пытается сделать ТС в своем коде), то выглядеть это будет так:

d_l={}
db_a.mean(axis=1)
for name_ex in  name_list:
d_r1={}
d_r1['u_mean']=db_a.mean(axis=1)[name_ex]
d_r1['c_mean']=db_b.mean(axis=1)[name_ex]
d_l[name_ex]=d_r1
print (d_l)

И соответствующий результат:

```
{'three':{'u_mean': 5.25, 'c_mean': 4.75}, 
 'four': {'u_mean': 9.5, 'c_mean': 5.0}, 
 'one':  {'u_mean': 4.0, 'c_mean': 3.5}, 
 'two':  {'u_mean': 4.0, 'c_mean': 5.5}, 
 'five': {'u_mean': 5.5, 'c_mean': 7.5}, 
 'seven':{'u_mean': 7.0, 'c_mean': 7.0}}
```

Разумеется, если универсальность не нужна, то задача существенно упрощается. Но надеюсь, такой тюнинг, а так-же рихтовку в случае, если что-то в условии осталось понято не верно, ТС сможет сделать самостоятельно. Ну, или задать дополнительные вопросы.